# Include local_policy and US_export_policy [JCE unlimited strength]

Tags: java, security, cryptography, policy, jce

Is it possible to include the local_policy and US_export_policy jars in my java application or in the JRE running on the enduser's system?

Or is it still only possible to replace both files?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice

Comment: @Henry On the contrary, it is a software deployment question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to include the local_policy and US_export_policy jars in my java application

No.

> or in the JRE running on the enduser's system?

Yes, that's how it has to be done. Installed in the target JRE.

> Or is it still only possible to replace both files?

I don't understand what difference you think there is between this question and the last part of the previous one. There isn't any.

Comment: include in the JRE meaning configure somewhere a path to the new policy jars without replacing the existing jars.